# Insert Integer in char array to use it in rename function

Tags: c++, c

it´s long ago since i tried to code sth. but i´m looking for a simple way of iterating through some folders to rename the containing files.

i have folder which look like 'MORE0001', 'MORE0002' etc. They contain all one file with the same name 'Data'

What i want to do is to rename all containing files to 'data.dat' (and maybe to find a way to extract the files out of the folders..)

so this is what it looks like:

```
   for (int i=0; i<10;i++){

   char oldname[]= "directory/MORE0001/data";
   char newname[]= "directory/MORE0001/data.dat";

   rename(oldname,newname);

   }
```

this works pretty fine, but i want to change the `0001` within the for-loop to `0002`etc..

hope you guys can help me.. i did not find an answer yet to this simple question

Comment: This does not look like a problem that needs a C program solution. This should be a Bash one-liner.

Comment: then tell me the answer please..

Comment: Bash: `for f in directory/MORE*/data; do mv $f $f.dat; done` But never take someone's word for it.  Replace the `mv` with `echo` as a dry-run, until you're happy with the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sprintf`:

```
char oldname[100];
char newname[100];
sprintf(oldname, "directory/MORE%04d/data", i);
sprintf(newname, "directory/MORE%04d/data.dat", i);
```

The 100 should be big enough to hold the pathname. If it's too short, your program will crash or (worse) rename your files into having unusable names.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it using C you can use the following statement to generate the string (that should be declared previously using something like char oldname[100]):

```
sprintf (oldname, "directory/MORE%04d/data", i);
```

The same to be done with newname.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have shown you how to use `sprintf()` in C, but you also tagged the question as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) as well.  In C++, you should use `std::ostringstream` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cstdio>  

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "directory/MORE" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << i << "/data";
    std::string oldname = oss.str();
    std::string newname = oldname + ".dat";
    std::rename(oldname.c_str(), newname.c_str()); 
}
```

That said, you should consider removing your integer-based loop and actually enumerate the content of the root `directory` to discover its subfolders dynamically.  You can use something like [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for that (which also has a [`rename()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename) function of its own), or even platform-specific APIs (like [`FindFirstFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx)/[`FindNextFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx) and [`MoveFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx) on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf` which will print formatted to a buffer, which you can pass into your `rename` function.

In `sprintf`, you can use `%04d` as your format specifier for `i` in your for loop, which will print leading zeros after your number up to 4 digits.